# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 while updating a record

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi i have seen that this question is already been asked but each of them are asked under insertion process, in my case i received this error while updating a record whether from PHPmyadmin or with my application,

```
UPDATE `posr_order` SET `deletion_date_time` = '2015-11-14 12:47:06' WHERE `order_id`='1'  AND `restaurant_id`='2'
```

Here is the code i m using to update a record.
The query succeeds all the time but i receive the error of

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Can anyone tell me why this error is showing.

Here is the Error which i got with php
[image]

And this is what i got with phpmyadmin
[image]

Comment: It simply means that number of columns you specify in query does not match with values you provided in the query.

Comment: the columns and values are same, you can see in the red image. I think i have issue with triggers which i have implemented in this table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be of few things

> 1. The value that you are updating the cell to exceeds the column length
> 2. There is a trigger that needs to be changed/removed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Subin i got it, i have triggers so i need to figure it out.

Comment: It can only be #2 (triggers). If it were an issue with an oversized value, the error would be different.